# Error in SQL statement using condition in having clause

Tags: sql

I have a `products` table with columns `id`, `price`, `category`, and `city`. I need to find the count of the cheapest `veggies` in a `Barcelona` city.

I tried this SQL query, but I get an error:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM products 
HAVING lower(category) = 'veggies' AND lower(city) = 'Barcelona' 
   AND price = (SELECT MIN(price)
                FROM products
                WHERE lower(category) = 'veggies' and lower(city) = 'Barcelona');
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation of sql

You need a where not a having here, and it comes before the joins

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM products pd 
Where lower(category) = 'veggies' AND lower(city) = 'Barcelona' 
AND price = (
   SELECT MIN(price) 
   FROM products pd
   WHERE lower(category) = 'veggies' and lower(city) = 'Barcelona'
);
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, the second where is in a subquery. Thanks

Comment: you are right! sorry  -- maybe some better indenting would aid in the readability?

Comment: yeah I also saw an issue... need to join to prices in the sub-query too.

Comment: There is only one table i.e products and the line "inner join prices" makes me think that there are 2 tables. Can you please explain this

Comment: @xedav90901 -- I think it was assumed you had two tables -- if you don't just take it out.

Answer (score -1):

The HAVING keyword is used when you're doing a group by, and need a where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM products 
WHERE city = 'Barcelona' and categories = 'veggies'
ORDER BY price asc
```

This will give you the cheapest veggies in Barcelona.

Comment: maybe you are missing a group by here?

Comment: Why do we need a group by? we don't need to aggregate anything so a group by isn't needed.

Comment: count here is going to give the count of the entire table not a specific veggie price point